# How to prevent Pkg.jl to hold state beyond Project.toml and Manifest.toml

Tags: julia

Julia's package manager `Pkg.jl` is great but sometimes it seems to hold state beyond entries in `Project.toml` or `Manifest.toml` and I wonder how this comes/how to prevent this.

Most recently I encountered this problem when changing one of my dependencies that I had used previously on tag `master` (added in package mode via `add DESPOT#master`) and wanted to use it in `dev` mode (e.g. in package mode runnign `dev ARDESOT`). However, somehow the package did not change to dev mode, so I tried removing it. After removing it, it was gone from both `Project.toml` and `Manifest.toml` (which is the expected behavior). However, restarting the REPL and running `Pkg.status()` still shows the entry for the removed package:
[image]
[image]

So I conclude that it holds state beyond `Manifest.toml` and `Project.toml`. Where is this information stored? Can I force to reset it somehow? Running the `Pkg` garbage collector does not do the trick. This has happened to me with multiple packages now, this is only the most recent example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is just a confusion about how `Pkg.status()` works. I am guessing your project is located withing a git repository? In that case `Pkg.status()` shows the diff vs the last commit in that repository, not the absolute status.

> However, restarting the REPL and running Pkg.status() still shows the entry for the removed package

Note that it is displayed as *removed*, note the red text, and also the `-` in front of the package name. This means that, compared to the last commit of your repo, this package has been removed.

> Where is this information stored?

In the last git commit.

Comment: Great, thank you! Good to know that it shows the diff against the last commit. I have also figured out that my problem in this case had a different reason and I was wrong to blame `Pkg` for not changing the version of the package.